# "Too many aggregate expressions" in Azure Stream Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I just extended the 'select' part of my Stream Analytics query, and suddenly get:
"Query compilation error: Too many aggregate expressions."

Searching for this error yields no results, except an old, google-cached page about 'Azure Stream Analytics Preview limitations' where it is said that 
"The maximum number of supported aggregate functions in a Stream Analytics job query definition is 7."

But that was for the *Preview* of course.

=> Is it normal to get this error with the current (GA) version of Stream Analytics? What is the limit?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is clear definition of maximum aggregates per query (15). As [per non-cached and non-preview official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931787.aspx).

> Note that you may have no more than 15 aggregates per query.

If you observe behavior different than that, it is good to bring attention - commenting on documentation or opening support ticket.